# Javascript countdown is going slow?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a countdown that is counting down in milliseconds; however, the countdown actually takes much longer than 7 seconds. Any idea as to why?

```
function countDown(time){
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        i++;

        if(i > time){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }else{
            //mining
            $('#mining_time').text($('#mining_time').text()-1);
        }

    }, 1);
}
```

And I can confirm the varible time passed to the function is correctly set to 7000.

Comment: hey i am sorry your other question was deleted as is the case here, when people can't answer they just delete it.

Comment: i made a fiddle for what you wanted mining based on probability...it's kinda fun. http://jsfiddle.net/TTy7Z/1/

Comment: ran it 1000 times it comes out pretty good... 
http://jsfiddle.net/TTy7Z/3/

Comment: why? this is huge limitation of javascript... javascript isn't concurrent. Meaning things can't happen simultaneously so if something is happening setInterval or setTimeout Won't be called till that happens. Javascript loops waiting for any events to occur than it calls whatever it attached to that event.

Comment: @Techsin Thank you Techsin! I appreciate the example. I could not for the life of me find a way to do it. Much thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a mostly-accurate countdown, use `setTimeout()`.

```
setTimeout(fn, 7e3);
```

If you absolutely must have it as close to 7 seconds as possible, use a tight poll (`requestAnimationFrame()`) and look at difference between the time of start and current poll.

```
var startTime = Date.now();
requestAnimationFrame(function me() { 
     var deltaTime = Date.now() - startTime;
     if (deltaTime >= 7e3) {
         fn();
     } else {
         requestAnimationFrame(me);
     }
});
```

Poly-fill as required.

Comment: Curious, why `requestAnimationFrame` is "better" than `setTimeout`?

Comment: I originally thought due to clamping issues when the tab isn't focused (clamped to 1s), but thinking about it, it might not be an issue.

Comment: From this perspective - `setTimeout` will be clamped to a lower resolution, while `requestAnimationFrame` will be completely suspended. http://jsfiddle.net/Wmmq7/ - open the page with console, then open another tab, wait for 10 second and return back

Comment: Using requestAnimationFrame will allow the browser to optimize multiple animations... In the current case, an element of the DOM is being modified. Not really sure that you'll gain something in terms of performance.

Answer (score 2):

1. the most precise way to run something after 7 seconds - is to use `setTimeout` with `7000` ms interval
2. a. there is no browser that guarantees an interval to run with 1ms resolution. In the best case it would be 7-10ms
3. b. there is only one thread in js, so the tasks are queued. It means that the next run will be scheduled to only after the current run is finished.

Some useful reading: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Answer (score 1):

No browser will take 1 as parameter for setInterval. Off the top of my head the minimum is 4 ms.

For an accurate result, get the current time, add 7000 ms, and poll (using setInterval or setTimeout) until you reach that new time.

A quick Web search returned [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/) that provides an example.

[Update] the value of 4 ms is mentioned on [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout).

Comment: "and poll (using setInterval)" --- any particular reason to use polled `setInterval` while `setTimeout` is available?

Comment: the OP needs to poll multiple times, so setInterval seems to make more sense here.